# VSC Extension creation

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, react-typescript

### Question:

How can you add settings for editor customizations, other extension customizations or anything from settings.json from a workspace to an extension? (and have the extension settings work)

### Code:

I currently have [this repo](https://github.com/XYIAN/yds-core) OR(not required) you can install [here at vsc marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YAMAHA.yds-core) where I am attempting to add settings.json but it is not being applied to the editor when downloaded.

For example, it would be perfect if there's a way to add it to contributes

```json
{
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "yds-core.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to apply settings from a settings.json to a workspace from an extension?

Or more specifically take a look at the settings.json I have in [this repo](https://github.com/XYIAN/yds-core) and let me know if there is some way I can have those be applied via extension?

I know there are theming extensions and ways to create theming but I was wondering about everything in my settings.json such as settings for other extensions like better comments presets etc.